# Replacing three integrators with one

Tags: matlab, simulink, integrator

I need to calculate a linear growth model (in simulink) with continuous-time signal, described as:

```
x’ = ax
```

with at least three different real parameters “a”.

I've managed to do it using three `integrators` as you can see in the image below:

[image: Diagram]

I've been told that there is a way to do it using only one integrator, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your gain blocks a vector, not just a scalar.

You can use a gain of `[1 0.8 1.2]` for a single gain block (with the multiplication mode set to `Element-wise`) instead of having three separate gain blocks set to `1`, `0.8`, and `1.2`.